# Change Java version for Tomcat running from Netbeans when invoked

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

I have a set of projects under Netbeans that run on Java 1.7; I am starting one that depends on having Java 1.8. It is a web app, and both Netbeans and the Tomcat server that is configured under Netbeans need to run on 8 for the latter project, but cannot run on 8 for any of the former projects.

I was hoping to create a bat file or something that would allow me to specify the Java version for both Netbeans and the Tomcat that runs under Netbeans.

I found the command line argument for setting the jdkhome for Netbeans; that works for Netbeans. But the JDK configured for the server appears to be a Netbeans setting, and I don't know how to change that at the time that I invoke Netbeans, or with an environment variable (I tried JAVA_HOME, that didn't work).

Does anyone know how/whether this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

Open netbeans IDE and go to Tools-->Servers

[image: Netbeans server settings]

Then Select your server (`tomcat`) and on `platform` tab select your JDK version and lick on `close` button.

[image: Select JDK platform]

if Your `JAVA platform` is not listed in combo box click on `Manage Platforms` and add new JAVA Paltform.

Comment: Well, this tells me/anyone how to set it within NetBeans; the question was how to set it "at the time that I invoke Netbeans, or with an environment variable". I'm trying to avoid having to do a number of manual operations to switch between environments.

Comment: @arcy then try to set `JRE_HOME` environmental variable